# Can we enter a [relationship]? Regards, [relationships]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Is there a reason for the existence of two separate tags [relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relationship) and [relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relationships)? The second one contains a more formal description, yet the first one is used more often.